# Is it possible to accumulate values with increment in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, templatetags

I would like to know if there is any way to sum values in a variable in a Django template using `{% for obj in objects %}`. Something like this:

```
for student in students:
         notes += student.note
```

Using the **mathfilters** or something similar to make the sum

Thanks!

Comment: Probably not. But you'll need to show more details of what you're trying to achieve, and explain why you couldn't do it in the view.

Comment: You could create a filter that does that... but you shouldn't. Logic should be in the view, not in the template. If you need to render this value, include it in the context for this template.

Comment: I guess you could by doing your own templatetags, but it is not recommended as the logic should go in the view rather than in the template.

Comment: Well it's not the first time I read that the logic should be implemented in the view ... hehe I will stop being stupid now ... but taking advantage of what you are here, for what I am going to do it will be necessary ... there is an expreção In python that replaces anything other than letter?

Answer (score 0):

If you want sum values in template you can use `with` tag
please read this link for more information
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#with

Comment: with `with` tag  you can define template value and can do operation with this value.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#add) filter.

> It is a not a good idea to do so anyway. You want to keep your logic inside the views and keep the rendering inside the templates.

You can also use [django-mathfilters](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mathfilters)

```
{% load mathfilters %}
{{ num1 | addition:num2 }}
```